# Is it possible to upgrade Azure Powershell (ISE) in Windows Server 2012 R2 without reinstalling?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, powershell-ise, azure-powershell

I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 in an Azure VM in which I have an older version of Azure Powershell (ISE) - when I run . I searched for instructions on how to update Azure Powershell (ISE) but all I'm finding is on how to install from scratch per http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/

Is there a way to upgrade without having to re-import the Azure subscription publish-settings file etc ?

By the way, an easy way to find out what version I'm on would be great. Doing get-module azure or get-module does not give me version info per http://cropme.ru/fc7037d19a74cd0db256c52142d9b98a

Answer (score 0):

After you upgrade the Azure PowerShell module, you can just run `Add-AzureAccount` to update your subscription settings.

Comment: Do you mean I should install a new Azure PowerSheel module by downloading and installing the Azure PowerShell module by running the Microsoft Web Platform Installer via  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=320376&clcid=0x409 ? And after I've done a new install (does it overwrite my old one ?) and then run "Add-AzureAccount" ? So does this mean the way to upgrade is to do a new install and run the "Add-AzureAccount" command ?

Comment: Yes, that would more or less be the process. If you run into issues, like I did, you might need to delete the `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows Azure PowerShell` directory.

Comment: Before attempting your suggestion, since I originally had installed a bunch of things using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 (which was now expired on my VM) I now installed the Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 trial version in the same VM and using tools, I was able to install updates to different Powershell tools. Once that was done I tried your link to but it only seems to install Azure Powershell (see http://cropme.ru/ae93a9c26e6a933c29a19fb63576bf38) whereas I wish to update Powershell ISE (Azure module).